# Pointer freezes every other second, whether on trackpad or mouse

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, mouse, freeze, touchpad

I recently updated my graphics driver because I got scanned my system and apparently it was 30 months out of date.
I updated it, and ever since, my mouse stopped working properly.

I have an HP Notebook:
Windows 10 - AMD A6-5200 APU with Radeon HD graphics - 4 GB of RAM - 64x based processor

OS Build: 14393.187

Pretty sure I have the latest verson of Radeon.

I tried a lot of things already, but nothing is working.  If all else fails, I can just clean install windows 10 again.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to do a system restore to an earlier point, see https://www.google.com/search?q=restore+to+earlier+point+windows+10&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab for the step by step process.  This will at least save you frustration while seeking a better answer.

Sometimes the auto update of drivers does so in a generic fashion without taking into consideration the "exact" configuration of your computer.  This is why it is best to check the driver update before okaying it.  You may have to set your updating program to alert you and require your approval first.

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work sadly :/

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't work, so it might be a hardware failure that just happened with the driver update.  I am going to clean install windows 10 again soon to see if that fixes it.  If not, might need to get a new computer.  The mouse freezing is really x100 annoying.